# Public Sub not firing after use of UserForm

Tags: excel, vba, userform, public

I have an issue where, once I use a userform within the file, the public sub that is inserting columns on my sheets stops working.  I run into this issue once I use this specific userform.  I can add certain information and have the public sub add in the new columns, however, once I use the one userform, it no longer functions.

A scenario that works with no problems:
- Import xml
- Add columns based on XML
- Add in new member
- Add column with new member

A scenario that does not work:
- Import XML
- Add columns based on XML
- Use macro/userform to make adjustment to any member
- Add in new member
- New column will not be added in for new member

I can continue to add in new members and update the amount of columns that are inserted, however, once I hit the button to call the adjustment userform, the functionality to add in new columns (or delete columns) goes away.

This is in the sheet module for the worksheet change that controls the amount of columns to be added/deleted

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
                                                                                                                                             
    Dim KeyCells As Range, colNum As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
        SOMESHEETS = "*C-Proposal-19*MemberInfo-19*Schedule J-19*NOL-19*NOL-P-19*NOL-PA-19*Schedule R-19*Schedule A-3-19*Schedule A-19*Schedule H-19*"
        Set KeyCells = Range("B30")
        If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target) Is Nothing Then
            If IsNumeric(KeyCells.Value) Then
                colNum = KeyCells.Value
                If colNum > 0 Then
                 For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
                     If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
                     If CBool(InStr(LCase(SOMESHEETS), LCase("*" & ws.Name & "*"))) Then
                            InsertColumnsOnSheet argSheet:=ws, argColNum:=colNum
                     End If
                     End If
                 Next ws
                End If
            End If
        End If
        

    
    SOMESHEETS = "*MemberInfo-20*C-Proposal-20*Schedule J-20*NOL-20*Schedule R-20*NOL-P-20*SchA-3-20*Schedule H-20*NOL-PA-20*Schedule A-20*Schedule A-5-20*"
    Set KeyCells = Range("B36")
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target) Is Nothing Then
        If IsNumeric(KeyCells.Value) Then
            colNum = KeyCells.Value
            If colNum > 0 Then
                For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
                    If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
                    If CBool(InStr(LCase(SOMESHEETS), LCase("*" & ws.Name & "*"))) Then
                            InsertColumnsOnSheet argSheet:=ws, argColNum:=colNum
                    End If
                    End If
                Next ws
            End If
        End If
    End If
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
          
ErrorHandler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

This is the code that controls the columns that are copied and where they are inserted for each page

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub InsertColumnsOnSheet(ByVal argSheet As Worksheet, ByVal argColNum As Long)

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim Rng As Range, c As Range
    Dim TotalCol As Long, LeftFixedCol As Long, i As Long
    Dim j As Integer, k As Integer
    
    With argSheet
        Set Rng = .Range("3:3")
        Set c = Rng.Find("END")
        
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            TotalCol = c.Column
            LeftFixedCol = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Member1", argSheet.Range("3:3"), 0) - 1
            j = .Range("B4").End(xlToRight).Column
            k = j - LeftFixedCol
            If argSheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
                If TotalCol < LeftFixedCol + argColNum + 1 Then
                    .Columns(j).Copy
                    .Columns(j + 1).Resize(, argColNum - k).Insert CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                        Application.CutCopyMode = False
                End If
                If TotalCol > LeftFixedCol + argColNum + 1 Then
                For i = TotalCol - 1 To LeftFixedCol + argColNum + 1 Step -1
                    .Columns(i).Delete
                Next i
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End With
     
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
          
ErrorHandler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

This is the code for the userform that seems to be causing the issue

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim N As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim Rng1 As Range
Dim Rng2 As Range
Dim Rng3 As Range
Dim Rng4 As Range
Dim Rng5 As Range


Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set Rng1 = ws.Range("6:6").Find(Me.TextBox2.Value)
Set Rng2 = ws.Range("6:6").Find(Me.TextBox6.Value)
Set Rng3 = ws.Range("6:6").Find(Me.TextBox5.Value)
Set Rng4 = ws.Range("6:6").Find(Me.TextBox4.Value)
Set Rng5 = ws.Range("6:6").Find(Me.TextBox7.Value)

N = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

If WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ws.Range("6:6"), TextBox2, ws.Range("6:6"), TextBox2) = 0 And ComboBox1 <> 0 Then
 MsgBox "Sorry, " & TextBox2 & " not found!"
    Else
If TextBox3.Value = "" And ComboBox1.Value <> "" Then
        MsgBox "There is no data to add", 48
    Else
    
If WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ws.Range("6:6"), TextBox6, ws.Range("6:6"), TextBox6) = 0 And ComboBox2 <> 0 Then
 MsgBox "Sorry, " & TextBox6 & " not found!"
    Else
If TextBox8.Value = "" And ComboBox2.Value <> "" Then
        MsgBox "There is no data to add", 48
    Else
    
If WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ws.Range("6:6"), TextBox5, ws.Range("6:6"), TextBox5) = 0 And ComboBox3 <> 0 Then
 MsgBox "Sorry, " & TextBox5 & " not found!"
    Else
If TextBox9.Value = "" And ComboBox3.Value <> "" Then
        MsgBox "There is no data to add", 48
    Else
    
If WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ws.Range("6:6"), TextBox4, ws.Range("6:6"), TextBox4) = 0 And ComboBox4 <> 0 Then
 MsgBox "Sorry, " & TextBox4 & " not found!"
    Else
If TextBox10.Value = "" And ComboBox4.Value <> "" Then
        MsgBox "There is no data to add", 48
    Else
    
If WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ws.Range("6:6"), TextBox7, ws.Range("6:6"), TextBox7) = 0 And ComboBox5 <> 0 Then
 MsgBox "Sorry, " & TextBox7 & " not found!"
    Else
If TextBox11.Value = "" And ComboBox5.Value <> "" Then
        MsgBox "There is no data to add", 48
    Else

For i = 5 To N
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "B").Value = frmAddAdj.ComboBox1.Value Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, Rng1.Column).Value = frmAddAdj.TextBox3.Text
    End If
    
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "B").Value = frmAddAdj.ComboBox2.Value Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, Rng2.Column).Value = frmAddAdj.TextBox8.Text
    End If
    
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "B").Value = frmAddAdj.ComboBox3.Value Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, Rng3.Column).Value = frmAddAdj.TextBox9.Text
    End If
    
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "B").Value = frmAddAdj.ComboBox4.Value Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, Rng4.Column).Value = frmAddAdj.TextBox10.Text
    End If
    
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "B").Value = frmAddAdj.ComboBox5.Value Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, Rng5.Column).Value = frmAddAdj.TextBox11.Text
    End If
Next i

End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If

ErrorHandler:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Unload frmAddAdj

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim ctl As MSForms.Control

    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        Select Case TypeName(ctl)
            Case "TextBox", "ComboBox"
                ctl.Text = ""
            Case "CheckBox", "OptionButton", "ToggleButton"
                ctl.Value = False
        End Select
    Next ctl
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim iRow As Integer, iMax As Integer

iRow = Cells.Find(What:="New Jersey Audit Adjustment", _
    LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Row

iMax = Cells.Find(What:="New Jersey Audit Adjustment", _
    LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Row
    
If ActiveSheet.Range("B" & iRow & ":B" & iMax).Cells.Count = 1 Then
    Me.ComboBox1.AddItem ActiveSheet.Range("B" & iRow & ":B" & iMax).Value
    Me.ComboBox2.AddItem ActiveSheet.Range("B" & iRow & ":B" & iMax).Value
    Me.ComboBox3.AddItem ActiveSheet.Range("B" & iRow & ":B" & iMax).Value
    Me.ComboBox4.AddItem ActiveSheet.Range("B" & iRow & ":B" & iMax).Value
    Me.ComboBox5.AddItem ActiveSheet.Range("B" & iRow & ":B" & iMax).Value
    
Else
    Me.ComboBox1.List = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & iRow & ":B" & iMax).Value
    Me.ComboBox2.List = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & iRow & ":B" & iMax).Value
    Me.ComboBox3.List = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & iRow & ":B" & iMax).Value
    Me.ComboBox4.List = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & iRow & ":B" & iMax).Value
    Me.ComboBox5.List = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & iRow & ":B" & iMax).Value
    
End If

ErrorHandler:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

I can't figure out why adding in the new columns stops after I use the add adjustment macro.  This is the last bit of code above.

I tried adding in the errorhandler but that didn't change the end result.  I also add a debugger to try and find out if there was an error, and it would pop up saying there was an error with no information being provided.  The line and description were blank, so that was no help.

Comment: Off-topic but I recommend to read about the `If … ElseIf … End If` construct to get rid of those multiple `End If` statements.

Comment: To analyze what's going on I highly recommend to go through the code step by step using F8. Then you see exactly which statements are executed and you will find out in which line your problem is. See also [Excel Easy - Debugging](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html) and [Debugging VBA Code](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/debugging-vba-code).

Comment: @ Pᴇʜ I finally figured out how to step through the whole process, and found that once I use the add adjustment macro/userform the Insert Columns code acts funky.  Once I use that macro the insert columns codes skips over the section starting at `If Not c Is Nothing Then`

Comment: That means `Set c = Rng.Find("END")` failed and didn't bring up any result. Please check the documentation of the [range.find method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find). You need to specify the parameters `LookIn`, `LookAt`, `SearchOrder`, and `MatchByte`. They are saved and have no default. Means when a user changed them in the user interface while searching, they change in your VBA code too. Always define them so you don't get randomly working/non-working code!